# Plotting a 4D numpy data using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I  have a 3D numpy array that has the dimensions 1400x1400x29. However, the data is 4D because for every x, y, z there is a different value (4th dimension). I believe that it can be done something like the below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

//some calculation that creates a 3D array  called "cube"

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
for x in range(1400):
    for y in range(1400):
        for z in range(29):
            ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=cube[x,y,z])
plt.show()
```

However, the above script gives me an error saying 
"TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()"

EDIT 1
Complete error message

```
File "cube.py", line 57, in <module>
    ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=cube[z , x , y], cmap=plt.hot())
  File "/pawsey/cle60up05/python/2.7.14/matplotlib/2.1.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-2.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 2353, in scatter
    xs, ys, s=s, c=c, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/pawsey/cle60up05/python/2.7.14/matplotlib/2.1.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-2.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1710, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/pawsey/cle60up05/python/2.7.14/matplotlib/2.1.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-2.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 4050, in scatter
    colors = mcolors.to_rgba_array(c)
  File "/pawsey/cle60up05/python/2.7.14/matplotlib/2.1.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-2.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/colors.py", line 231, in to_rgba_array
    result = np.empty((len(c), 4), float)
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add the complete error message.

Comment: @DYZ I have edited the question with the complete error message

Comment: what code `cube` do? maybe add that code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So understanding `cube` is a `numpy.ndarray` of shape `(1400, 1400, 29)`, the proper way to plot a 3D scatter would be:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

//some calculation that creates a 3D array  called "cube"

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
X, Y, Z = np.mgrid[:1400, :1400, :29]
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c=cube.ravel())
plt.show()
```

You have to call `ax.scatter` with arrays, not scalars. Also, it takes a 1D array as `c` input, so I called `ravel()`. `np.mgrid` is just a fast way to create uniform grids of N-dimensions. It is equivalent to a `np.meshgrid` of `np.arange`. I suggest you read the documentation of each of those if you want to know more.